# Styling Gtk.Label object

Tags: gtk, vala

I have a [vala](/questions/tagged/vala) app, that I want to style the label window object, I tried the following:

```
 public Object createConfirm(){
        var window = new Gtk.Window ();
        var grid = new Gtk.Grid () {
            orientation = Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL,
            column_spacing = 6,
            row_spacing = 6
        };
        window.add(grid);
        window.title = "Shutdown Confirmation";
        window.border_width = 10;
        window.window_position = Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER;
        window.set_default_size (350, 80);
        window.destroy.connect (Gtk.main_quit);

        var label = new Gtk.Label(null);
        var label_text = "Are you sure to turn off now?";
        label.set_markup("<b>"+label_text+"</b>");
        
...
```

In that way `label.set_markup` succeeded only in bolding the label text. When I try `set_markup("<h3>"+label_text+"</h3>")` or `set_markup("<span style=\"color:red\">"+label_text+"</span>")` or using any tag other than `<b>` it does not return any string on the label window. Why does it happened? and is there a simple solution in which I don't have to use any extra dependency?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to change style values dynamically, the recommended way to style labels (and all other widgets) is with CSS.

In your app startup code, you can create an app-wide [Gtk.CssProvider](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.CssProvider.html) from a CSS file. Then, when you build your widgets, add a style class to your label using `label.get_style_context().add_class()`.

---

The markup language looks like HTML, but it is not. [Here is a guide to the available tags and attributes](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/pango-markup-language.html). Most notably, there is *no* CSS here, and text styles are added using attributes on `<span>` elements.